# Can notepad++ replace Adobe Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, notepad++

I remember when I was very surprised when I realised that everything I'm doing in Adobe Dreamweaver I can do without Dreamweaver. Just coding in Notepad++.

I see now that Notepad++ can edit actionscript files. So is it really the truth that everything I can do in Adobe Flash, I can do just coding in Notepad ?

If yes, could you recommend me a good tutorial for beginners.

Comment: That depends on 'what' you want to do in Adobe Flash, doesn't it? Drawing for example is possible through code, but it takes forever and looks like a mess from my experience. simple shapes are fine, anything complex isn't. And sure, you can write and edit your code even in the standard windows editor. you still need to compile your code though, through the FLEX compiler for example.

Comment: @DodgerThud, I'm mainly interested in moving images along bezier paths. According to your experience, is it suitable to do in a coding way?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with bezier paths, but you should be able to make it work. What is suitable and what is not depends mainly on you. For example, I can 'draw' a rectangle in AS3 in like 4-5 lines. But I could also simply draw in Flash Pro and export it as a swc. Both approaches are fine and depend on the complexity of the project as well as your personal preferences.

Comment: @bonaca - I'm specialized in Bezier curves. If you are interested in moving images along Bezier paths, you can ask in a special thread: " How can I make an object move along a Bezier curve?". I will answer you with pleasure.

Comment: You don't have to use Flash just like you don't have to use Photoshop.  You should look at all the things Flash does and wonder why you don't do them too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do most of the stuff (drawing vector graphics, importing bitmaps, sounds, animation) with code, you don't need Flash for that. However, you will not be able to compile your `.as` files to `.swf` without Flash or additional tools.

You should try [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) (it's free), it has syntax highlighting (better than Flash Professional, IMHO) and many helpful tools to compile and debug your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I then compile `.as` to `.swf` using `FlashDevelop`?

Comment: @bonaca Yes, you need FlexSDK installed (it's also freeware).